# How to fix ArgumentError in Admin::Payments#show : wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I try to add a "show" Interface for payments on Active Admin, so I added this code to my file "app/admin/payments.rb" :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Payment do
    actions :index, :show

    index do 
        column "Actions" do |payment|
            links = []
            links << link_to("View", admin_payment_path(payment))
            links.join(" <br><br> ").html_safe
        end
    end

    show do
        attributes_table do
            row :id
            row :remote_id
            row :credit_card_id
            row :State
            row :Refund_id
            row :Created_at
            row :updated_at
            row :amount
            row :currency
            row :subscription_id
        end
        active_admin_comments
    end
end
```

And I call this show action like that :
    link_to("View", admin_payment_path(payment))

I have the following error thaht I can not understand :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:show)
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:58:in `__temp__d6564786f646'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/display_helper.rb:30:in `display_name_method_for'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/display_helper.rb:18:in `display_name'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:175:in `method_missing'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb:36:in `default_title'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb:14:in `title'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:25:in `block in build_active_admin_head'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:24:in `build_active_admin_head'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:9:in `build'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `block in __ruby_bundler_gems_active_admin__ca___f__ab__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__2881818806947822812_77228080'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `new'
  /ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `__ruby_bundler_gems_active_admin__ca___f__ab__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__2881818806947822812_77228080'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:233:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:161:in `to_html'
  responders (1.0.0) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:104:in `to_html'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154:in `respond'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330:in `respond_with'
  inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:13:in `show'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:463:in `_run__1186283259363649751__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  airbrake (9.0.2) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:33:in `call!'
  airbrake (9.0.2) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:21:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4337536015866295967__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


  Rendered /ruby/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /ruby/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /ruby/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (10.3ms)
```

Thank you for your help, I am a beginner in Ruby On Rails and ActiveAdmin

Comment: The codes in the `app/admin/payments.rb` file must be in the `ActiveAdmin.register Payment do ...codes should be in here... end` block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is already in this block, I forgot to write it in my post. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the block opened by `attributes_table do` isn't closed, so I'd start by adding an `end` after the last `row` line and seeing if the error changes or disappears.

Also, for what it's worth, based on ActiveAdmin's API documentation, I don't think the line `actions :index, :show` is necessary -- it specifically says that ["all CRUD actions are enabled by default"](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#disabling-actions-on-a-resource), so there shouldn't be a need to explicitly define those actions. I might try taking it out and seeing what happens.

Comment: Sorry but this block is closed. I removed the line action :index, :show but the same error occurs

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct -- I misread it based on the indentation. 

Taking another look through the documentation, it seems like `row` may be expecting [symbols rather than strings](https://activeadmin.info/6-show-pages.html) (i.e. `:id` and `:remote_id` instead of `"id"` and `"remote_id"`) as its arguments. Can you try that and see if it helps?

Comment: I replaced strings by symbols and the same error occurs =(

Comment: Can you share the view where you're using `link_to`?

Comment: I just added it on my topic

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates ActiveAdmin is not finding a default title for the page, so try:

```
show title: 'Payment' do
  ...
end
```

or define a display_name() method on the Payment model.